# Given a table how to solve a query

Tags: sql

I am working on the following query but it seems that I'm not getting it right. I would appreciate the help.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  fid   INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY,  
  weight  FLOAT   NOT NULL  COMMENT "(kg)")

CREATE TABLE bar (
  bid INTEGER,
  fid INTEGER,
  height FLOAT NOT NULL COMMENT "(attoparsecs)",
  PRIMARY KEY (bid),
  FOREIGN KEY (fid) REFERENCES foo)
```

Note that fid may be NULL in bar.

(1)  Write the SQL query to list all attributes of bars that don't have a matching foos.

(2)  Write a second query to list all attributes of foos that don't have any matching bars.

What I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM bar LEFT JOIN foo ON bar.fid = foo.fid
WHERE foo.fid IS NULL;

SELECT * FROM foo LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.fid = bar.fid
WHERE bar.fid IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

(1) Write the SQL query to list all attributes of bars that don't have a matching foos.

```
select * from bar where fid NOT IN (select fid from foo) or fid is null
```

(2) Write a second query to list all attributes of foos that don't have any matching bars

```
select * from foo where fid NOT IN (select distinct fid from bar)
```